# Apply formatting to a row in ag-Grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am using a Ag-grid and have a requirement to set the last row (kind of total) to be bold and some background.
How can I achieve considering that we define columns ?
Also while the last row label (i.e. 1st column last row of grid) can be identified by checking params.value === 'Total', the other columns of that row can have dynamic total values (so cannot compare their actual text)
Below is how the config looks like (just for one of the columns)

```
   [ {
            headerName: '',
            field: 'Status',
            width:  defaultWidth,
            tooltipField:'status',
            headerTooltip: 'Status',
            sortable: false,
            resizable: false,
            cellStyle: params => {
              if (params.value === 'Total') {
                return { backgroundColor: color.orange,"font-weight":"bold" };
              } else {
                return null;
              }
            }
        }, {.....}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style the last row by using the Grid Option `getRowStyle`:

```
  getRowStyle: (params) =>
    params.node.lastChild
      ? { backgroundColor: 'orange', 'font-weight': 'bold' }
      : null
```

Relevant Documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/row-styles/

See this implemented in the following sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/Vu32lW7jROiN0h5Q